# Finding pairs in an sorted array with big values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently stuck on a problem with finding pairs in an sorted array with big values. Example: if i get the array sortedarr=[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] as input. It should return pairs = 15.

I have written the below code, which works in O(N2) for both unsorted and sorted arrays. But the code is very basic and i would like for it to be able to manage sorted arrays in an faster time. I guess that the easiest way is to just compare the current element with the one next to it. But i don't know how i can do that. How can i manage to change the code so it will fulfill my requirements?

```
    public static int countpairs(int[] sortedarr) {
        int N = sortedarr.length;
        int pairs = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (sortedarr[i] == sortedarr[j]) {
                    pairs++;
                }
            }
        }
        return pairs;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want the number of distinct pairs you can build from repeated elements in the array?

Comment: How it is running in O(N)?

Comment: Yes that is correct! :) @jrook

Comment: I wrote wrong, i have edited the post @KousikMandal

Comment: In that case, you just need to count the number of repeated element and then calculate C(p1,2) + C(p2,2) + ... . If there are six 2s and four 5s in the array, the result is C(6,2) + C(4,2) = 15 + 6 = 21. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. But the problem is that i don't know how to write the code to count the number of repeated element and then calculate it. @jrook

Comment: You can count the dupes easily in a sorted array by just looking at each element and the next one. This can be done in one pass over the array and is O(N). The rest is straightforward (remember that `C(x,2) = x*(x-1)/2`)

Comment: I posted an answer, but I really recommend that you try this yourself first. It is fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in O(N), instead of O(N^2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a= new int[] {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3};
    int i = 0;
    int n = a.length;
    int ans = 0;
    while(i < n - 1) {
        int dupeCount = 1;
        while(i < n - 1 && a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
            dupeCount++;
            i++;
        }
        if(dupeCount > 1) {
            ans = ans + (dupeCount * (dupeCount-1) / 2);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Outputs 15.

The idea is somewhat similar to what Bubble sort uses. We just need to look at each item and its successor in the array to see if it is a duplicate or not. From there, the number of distinct pairs that can be created is just `C(dupeCount,2) = dupeCount * (dupeCount - 1) / 2`. And we sum all such occurrences to get the final answer.

Comment: I think thats the fastest solution, you have to iterate through the array and doing it once is the fastest approach. There may be some optimizations for special cases (like if you know the distribution or likelihood), but this solution is definitely in `O(n)` and every other will be as well.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this helps you, please accept the answer. Cheers! @Jacki222